# Can't Enable "Show app notifications" in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading from Windows 8.1 Single Language to Windows 10 Home Single Language, I cannot receive any notifications on screen. When i went to the notifications settings the "Show app notification" toggle is disabled and a message saying that "Some settings are managed by your organisation" is displayed. This is my personal PC and does not belong to any domain. Moreover, I cannot access gpedit.msc (does not exist). Any idea how to make the notifications working? It's really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I used [this](http://betaleaf.net/how-to-enable-app-notifications-when-managed-by-your-organization/) solution. But instead of downloading the code, I went right through the regedit (Win Key + R > regedit) and edited the key to:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
>   “NoToastApplicationNotification”=dword:00000000

After restarting windows I could enable the option "Show app notifications".

Comment: Another cause of this is something like BitDefender running in AutoPilot mode, where if it detects a Movie/Work program (so Media Player / Visual Studio) it disables the notifications - turning off AutoPilot fixes that